# How can I use Java codes in PHP?

Tags: java, php

I have a php code and java codes(exactly 3 java files in 1 package).
I want to use java codes and variables in my php code.

I think I should include java file first like this

```
<?php include 'sample.java'; ?>
```

but I'm not sure about this and even if it's right, I don't know what to do next.

I found an old example in Korean web page :

```
// HelloWorld.java
public class HelloWorld
{
String hw = "Hello World";


public String getHelloWorld()
{
return hw;
}
}

// HelloWorld.php
<?
$myObj = new Java("HelloWorld");
echo (string) $myObj->getHelloWorld();
?>
```

(I think it should be `<?php ?>` not `<? ?>` , anyway they didn't work both)
but it doesn't work and texts were shown on my page :

// HelloWorld.java public class test { String hw = "Hello World"; public String getHelloWorld() { return hw; } } // HelloWorld.php

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Java' not found in */*my directory*/* Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in */*my directory*/*

How can I use my java codes in php?

Comment: You cant include java in php. thats 2 completely different things! Thats like to drive your car in the sky. You cant do it!

Comment: Use either PHP or Java (JSF) - or if you want both, use APIs between these (Microservice approach) - but executing Java from PHP most likely isn't a great idea.

Comment: The code you're quoting above seems to use [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/index.php), which you'd have to set up before using class Java and so on. There's no native Java integration in core PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all java and php have different runtime environment so you can not include your java file to php. But you can compile your java part to an own programm and execute it from php by `exec()` `system()`. But than you need to think about how to get data from php to java and the result back to php. But it sounds like your java part is not a complete program, so you would need to learn both laguages. Better is to look if you find a library which will have the same functionality than your java files

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly include java classes in your php files. To execute java, you need to first compile java code using javac and then execute the generated bytecode using java.

It is still doable, but the process is bit more involved.

You need to write your java program to work like a command line program where you could pass commands/switches to it and based on your parameters, call some method. Then you would need to create a jar file out of your compiled classes and make it a executable jar by adding main class into MANIFEST-MF.

For example :

```
java -jar yourjar.jar hello

output :
Hello World
```

In PHP, you could use shell_exec function to call this

```
<?
shell_exec("java -jar /home/workspace/target/yourjar.jar hello");
?>
```

Comment: @maio290 Interesting. Why shouldn't a beginner be learning something? What makes you adjudicator of what a beginner should and should not learn?

Comment: I'm with JJ, My very first web application ever.. This is exactly what i did.. I wrote my code in Java.. Had a website in php, And I horribly packaged the application, but It did exactly what i wanted.. I learned from it and would never write such an abomination today.